# ios score open graph

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

My understanding is that when I create an FB app that is a game and uses the score API then several open Graph Actions/Objects are created automatically so as to offer the functionality to see highscore information posted to mine and my friends feeds. Indeed I created a FB canvas app and see High Score, Play Open Graph actions automatically created.

I have now created a new app that is for native iOS only and is set up as a game and uses the scores API. However the score open graph actions mentioned previously are not automatically created nor do I see any updates on high scores in mine or my friends feeds when using the app. I have checked in desktop FB as well as the FB mobile app.

Any info would be really helpful.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

David, You have to implement your open graph app using a hosting server (heroku is great) to hold your objects and actions. Watch the Open Graph and Mobile video here --> http://developers.facebook.com/videos/

The Wishlist app they created helps a lot in understanding how it should work.